# Join with union returns me wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I need to use union all twice. And then to join them with the same table. First union will contain a where statement and the second it will not.
Problem is that when I use the second table my result is changing.

```
select sum(x.quantity*x.Price)
from CustomerTrans t1 
inner join (
    select *
    from InventoryTrans
    union all
    select *
    from InventoryTransTemp
) x on t1.TrnDocumentID = x.TrnDocumentID
group by t1.TrnDocumentID
```

Here is the output from this result

[First Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR7JL.png)
[image]

Then I am adding the second union with the where statement inside

```
select sum(x.quantity*x.Price), sum(x2.quantity*x2.Price)
from CustomerTrans t1 
left join (
    select *
    from InventoryTrans
    union all
    select *
    from InventoryTransTemp
) x on t1.TrnDocumentID = x.TrnDocumentID
left join (
    select *
    from InventoryTrans
    where printed = 2 or InvoicePaymentID = 2 
    union all
    select *
    from InventoryTransTemp
    where printed = 2 or InvoicePaymentID = 2
) x2 on t1.TrnDocumentID = x2.TrnDocumentID 
group by t1.TrnDocumentID
```

Here is the second result

[Second Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hndCO.png)
[image]

Second result it should be 3.80 and not 7.60

It look like it multiples my price *2 instead *1.

Comment: 1) Please don't use images for code, data or errors. 2) We need to see sample data and expected results to understand what you are trying to accomplish. 3) Its a very common problem to multiply the results when joining, because if you have multiple rows in the joined table you will double your original number of rows.

Comment: Thank you Dale. ''because if you have multiple rows in the joined table you will double your original number of rows'' I think thats my problem.

Comment: When debugging sums you should start by removing the sum and verifying that the rows being returned are correct - then issues like this show up immediately. Adding the sum/group by should be the very last stage of building the query.

Comment: Is it possible to use a case without to group by my columns in the end?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean - sorry. For a good question you need a [mre] which includes sample data, expected results, explanation of logic as to why said results are expected and your best attempt to date. Ideally post your sample data as DDL+DML to allow people to copy and paste it straight out and begin testing right away.

Comment: You're using an `inner join` on your first query and two `left join` on the 2nd query. Surely your results will not match.

Comment: Your statement "Second result it should be 3.80 and not 7.60" is unclear Why do you think that? (Please use [edit] to add that  info to your question)

Comment: I think the problem is quite clear. The first subquery has no `WHERE` clause, while the second does. So the first total must not be less than the second, or at least one would think so. The OP mentions the second value 7.6 is by the factor 2 too high. The reason for this to happen is joining before aggregating. It must be the other way round :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that you join rows you don't want to join. Let's say your first subquery returns

```
+----------+-------+
| quantity | price |
+----------+-------+
|       10 |   100 |
|       10 |   200 |
+----------+-------+
```

for a particular document ID. And your second subquery returns only

```
+----------+-------+
| quantity | price |
+----------+-------+
|       10 |   200 |
+----------+-------+
```

The joined result is:

```
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
| x.quantity | x.price | x2.quantity | x2.price |
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
|         10 |     100 |          10 |      200 |
|         10 |     200 |          10 |      200 |
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

And the aggregations results thereafter are:

```
+----------+-----------+
| x_result | x2_result |
+----------+-----------+
|     3000 |      4000 |
+----------+-----------+
```

instead of

```
+----------+-----------+
| x_result | x2_result |
+----------+-----------+
|     3000 |      2000 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Instead of joining single rows, you want to join aggregation results (the totals per document):

```
select 
  ct.*,
  coalesce(u1.total, 0) as u1_total,
  coalesce(u2.total, 0) as u2_total
from customertrans ct
left join 
(
  select trndocumentid, sum(quantity * price) as total
  from
  (
    select * from inventorytrans
    union all
    select * from inventorytranstemp
  ) union1
  group by trndocumentid
) u1 on u1.trndocumentid = ct.trndocumentid
left join 
(
  select trndocumentid, sum(quantity * price) as total
  from
  (
    select * from inventorytrans where printed = 2 or invoicepaymentid = 2 
    union all
    select * from inventorytranstemp where printed = 2 or invoicepaymentid = 2
  ) union2
  group by trndocumentid
) u2 on u2.trndocumentid = ct.trndocumentid 
group by ct.trndocumentid
order by ct.trndocumentid;
```